# How can I scan the entire cassandra table which has 10B entries and no indexing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, dsbulk

I have a cassandra database which contains a table over 10B entries with no indexes. I need to get every row and do some data grouping. However I did using java & spring boot framework and it only scanned 2B records which is the cassandra limit on select * from abc.abc as documented here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14683
Is there a way in java to do it ? I tried ds bulk but that count whole table and does not read each row.

Comment: dsbulk count will count rows, but that depends on your dsbulk query.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you mentioned, CASSANDRA-14683, refers to a limitation where SELECT statements without a specific partition key can only scan up to 2 billion rows.

Alternative approach to solve this could be using Pagination using token range and read your data in chunks untill all the data is fetched.

Something like below:

```
 private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 10000; // Number of rows to fetch per page

public void getData() {
    try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().build()) {
        Metadata metadata = session.getMetadata();
        TokenRange fullRange = metadata.getTokenMap().get().getPagingTokenRange();
        PagingIterable<Row> rows = session.execute(createPagingQuery(fullRange));
        for (Row row : rows) {
            // Process your data
        }
    }
}

private String createPagingQuery(TokenRange range) {
    return "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE token(partition_key) >= " + range.getStart().getValue()
            + " AND token(partition_key) <= " + range.getEnd().getValue()
            + " LIMIT " + PAGE_SIZE;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but in Cassandra, the LIMIT clause restricts the number of rows returned within a single query, but it does not enable automatic pagination or continuation of fetching subsequent pages beyond the initial LIMIT

Comment: @Anish using the resultset does has limit of 2B. Updated my answer.

Comment: How does the above code overcomes the 2billion mark? also does the above code execute multiple queries ? I see just one session.execute

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by scan, but you have two options when you want all of the data within a Cassandra table:

dsbulk
spark

Trying to do a query like `select * from foo.bar` is never going to be efficient and will more than likely timeout with 10B rows.

The above two applications will break the queries down into partition range queries and you can set throttles to limit the number of operations so you don't get those same timeouts.

With dsbulk, you can get a count, or you can unload the data to a csv if you need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally possible to process such an amount of data.

Your issue is likely relative to the abstraction layer (*Spring Data Cassandra*). The java drivers can easily process this amount data with 2 features (that can be used at the same time):

- **Paging:** Very well [describe in the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/manual/core/paging/)
- **Distribute the query among multiple nodes (map/reduce) with a token map**. To do so you are using TokenRanges as describe by other. You can know more about it in the [official documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/manual/core/metadata/token/) as well.

**1/ Spark**

Spark uses the token range trick. You should look at [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) (SCC). Now it is scala and a spark runtime.

**2/ DSBulk**

Allows only data copy or count so not something you can use to process you data.

**3/ Apache Beam**

A not-so-famous great way to process in a distributed way. It distributes the load among nodes as well and java compatible. [code](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/cassandra).  Hre some [sample](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/cassandra/CassandraIO.html)

Comment: With ds bulk copy, I imagine it must be using some sort of technique to copy (lets say 10B) data. Do you know if it uses regular select statement or copy the data buffer ? In case it uses the  select st there it must be facing or has faced same problem

Comment: DSbulk using the token range techni, then paging within the token range. With DSBulk you would dump the data as CSV and then updload again. It is OSS go ahead https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk